# How to access JSON response key/value in OnComplete ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an action which is returning this:

```
return Json(new { success = true, aaa = "bbb"  }, "text/html");
```

How can I access `aaa` in my onComplete function?

```
    onComplete: function (file, response)
    {
        alert(response['aaa']); //undefined
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `onComplete` in jQuery. Which Ajax method are you using? You could try `console.dir(reponse)` in place of your alert to see exactly what is in the `response` parameter.

The [`$.ajax()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) lets you provide a `complete` handler (without the "on"), or to actually process the response I'd use a `success` handler:

```
$.ajax("yourURLhere", {
       success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           alert(data['aaa']);
       },
       complete : function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
           // do something - note that the parameters don't include "data"
           // like the success callback, and "complete" is called after
           // the "success" or "error" callback
       }
});
```